# Web scraping data and then showing and updating it on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe which can showing and update data on the dataframe. I find this method to create a loop and output the data, it looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

def priceTracker():
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL'

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
    price = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
    print(price)

while True:
    priceTracker()
```

I want to create a dataframe to store the output and using loop function which can update the data in the row, may I know is there has solution to fix it?

Comment: Fix what? Do you get an error? What kind? Where's the traceback?

Comment: Please insert a delay between web requests.

Answer (score 1):

Why loop? when you can use `read_html()` method:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_html('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL')
```

Finally use `concat()` method:

```
result=pd.concat(data)
```

Comment: I would like to get the real-time price so I use web scraping method.

Comment: but for this using loop creates an infinite loop condition and at last(if you are using jupyter notebook) it will abort the connection